# How do I get a solarized color theme in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, color-theme

I'm used to using my IDE with the Solarized Dark color theme. I recently switched to Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and want to continue using that color theme. When I search for `solarized` in the extension manager it unfortunately doesn't find an extension. Is there still I way for me to get my desired color-theme?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.ColorThemesforVisualStudio

Comment: Are you just unable to find THAT theme, or are you unable to find ANY themes? Did you look online about themes in the full Visual Studio and where they are found?

Comment: For VS2019 install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor
It contains the solarized theme as one of the default theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solarized/Solarized Light Theme is available in [Color Themes For Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio). Simply search and download that plugin, and select Solarized/Solarized Light in Settings.

Answer (score -1):

This should work, and also in VS 2019.
Take a backup of your own settings before importing.

https://github.com/leddt/visualstudio-colors-solarized/blob/master/vs2017/solarized-light.vssettings